# Buddypress members not listed

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

Trying to import members to my website which is using buddypress from an sql dump. I tried inserting  the details in wp_xprofile_data and wp_users tables but it is not showing up in buddypress members area. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they need an entry in wp_usermeta -> meta_key = last_activity  & meta_value = 2012-06-04 21:51:03 
before they will show up any where. 
So if they haven't logged in at least once, they won't show up.
As part of your import, create a last_activity entry.

Depending on how you have BP set-up, you may also need to 'activate' members.